# Excel DataValidation List exclude value in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone think of a clever way i can exclude a value in a data validation list?

currently i am using a dropdown(A1) to then generate a dependant dropdown(A2) using this in the data validation list source

```
 =INDIRECT(LEFT(A1,5)&"LIST")
```

The first 5 chars in the first dropdown values makes part of the named range for the second dropdown

However in these dependent lists there is values i want to ignore which all contain the words "DO NOT USE"

I cant remove them from the named ranges but i would like to not show them in the second dropdown if possible

I know named ranges can be made up of multiple ranges but I'm not sure if that is possible to dynamically generate that with an array formula especially in the source box using just 1 named range (i need to keep the named range including the "xxx DO NOT USE" for other things and id rather not create multiple named ranges for the sames lists if this is possible as the "xxx DO NOT USE" may  change to able to use in the future and "DO NOT USE" will be removed from the value)

Comment: You could use dynamic range names for the dependent ranges, omit the "DO NOT USE" line altogether and use only the populated rows.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, these get updated with new data often and they may need to be used in the future(DO NOT USE may dissappear from the cell in update)...  but so far i see no way of array formula in the source list box